# Popup doesn't hide when touch outside

Tags: android, scroll, popupwindow

I need to dismiss my popup window when tapped on an empty place, but when scroll I need to show a popup. Now my popup window is hidden when I scroll, please help me resolve this issue. Here is my code :

```
private void showPopup(View view, String text) {
    if (infoPopup == null) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
        View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, null);
        TextView tvPopupText = popupView.findViewById(R.id.tv_popup);
        tvPopupText.setText(text);
        FrameLayout flBackground = popupView.findViewById(R.id.fl_bg);
        flBackground.setBackground(new BubbleDrawable(getContext(), R.color.azure, 16, 16, 8));
        infoPopup = new PopupWindow(popupView,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        infoPopup.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        // infoPopup.setOutsideTouchable(true);
        infoPopup.showAsDropDown(view);
        infoPopup.setTouchInterceptor(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE) {
                    dismissInfoPopup();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    } else {
        dismissInfoPopup();
    }
}

private void dismissInfoPopup() {
    if (infoPopup != null) {
        infoPopup.dismiss();
    }
    infoPopup = null;
}
```

Now popup window is shown when I scroll but when I tap outside popup doesn't hide.

Comment: Can you share the dismissInfoPopup() code as well?

Comment: @anna check my answer below

Comment: I think `infoPopup.setCancelable(true)` should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Add below line after popup display

```
infoPopup.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
infoPopup.setOutsideTouchable(true);
```

**EDIT**

```
infoPopup.setFocusable(true);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but now popup is hide when I scroll. I need to hide popup only when I touch.

Comment: @anna post the screenshot of the desired functionality